# renaming files in folders to test for dependencies

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm attached to a network drive with a ridiculously slow connection speed (15 kb/s on good days). I'm deleting most files but don't want to break a few files that have include statements. These are files for an enterprise app (mainly written in ColdFusion). My idea is to prefix a '_' to all file names as to test if the few files I want to keep get messed up. I already searched the code of files I want to keep for include statements, this is just to test before pushing live.

Is there a script I can run that would rename all files and folders but exclude 2 folders and the files in them? If there's a better way I'm open to options.

So I'd normally delete all files I think aren't needed, but since the network speed is terrible that would take a long time. Since this is testing if I make a mistake there could be a lot of deleting and undeleting, that's why I want to just rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest appending an extension of `._` instead of prefixing the name with `_`. That will make it easier to undo the rename.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set root="X:\"
set skip1="X:\folder1\"
set skip2="X:\folder2\"
for /r %root% %%F in (*) do (
  if /i "%%~dpF" neq %skip1% if /i "%%~dpF" neq %skip2% ren "%%F" "%%~nxF._"
)
```

To revert back to the original names:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set root="X:\"
for /r %root% %%F in (*._) do ren "%%F" "%%~nF"
```

**EDIT:**
 The first script to rename the files can be made faster by renaming all files in a directory with a single REN command.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set root="X:\"
set skip1="X:\folder1\"
set skip2="X:\folder2\"
for /r %root% %%F in (.) do (
  if /i "%%~fF" neq %skip1% if /i "%%~fF" neq %skip2% ren "%%~F\*.*" *.*._
)
```

The second script to revert the names must continue to rename each file individually.

I also added SETLOCAL to all scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a network drive you might not have permission to execute scripts.